# Sizzle returning only one element while selector matches two

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, sizzle

Sizzle does not return all the elements which match the selector. Here is [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/kogehu/1/edit?html,js,console) showing the problem.

#### HTML

```
<h4> Playing with Sizzle JS </h4>

  <ul class="list">
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li class="row"> Item 2 </li>
    <li class="row"> <span>Item 3</span> </li> 
    <li class="divider">List item with unique class name </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list">
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li class="row"> Item 2 </li>
    <li class="row"> <span>Item 3</span> </li> 
    <li class="divider">List item with unique class name </li>
  </ul>
```

#### JS

```
var selector = 'UL.list > LI:eq(1)';
var elements = Sizzle(selector);

console.log(elements.length); //Says 1
```

My Question is:

**Why it returns only 1 element while there are 2 elements which match the selector?**
How can I make sizzle to return all matching elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UL.list > LI:eq(1)` will only ever return one element: the 2nd element that matches `UL.list > LI`, as indicated by `:eq(1)`.

If you're looking for all `li` elements, remove the `:eq()`.

If you're looking for every `li` that is the second child, use `:nth-child()`:

```
var elements = Sizzle('UL.list > LI:nth-child(2)');
```